# How to decompose an integer in two other ones

Tags: python

I need to decompose a given integer in the form `n = ab(a+b)`. Since b can be at least 1, we restrain `a` to go up to `ceil(sqrt(n)).` By symmetry of both variables, we find that b can go up to `ceil(sqrt(n/(2*a))).` The code I used is below. When I provide `n=30=2*3*(2+3)` or some other examples, it provides the correct answer. When I provide `9510432 = 1256*6*(1256+6)` it is providing `(0,0)` which is wrong. While when I provide a 15 or longer digit number, it is just too slow. Can you help me understand this, i.e. why it is sometimes wrong sometimes correct ? How can I make it more efficient concerning the time complexity ? I eventually tried to use combinations from itertools in order to get a list of tuples but did not succeed in implementing it correctly.

```
import math as m
from itertools import combinations
def decompose(n):
   a = 0
   b = 0
   for i in range(1, m.ceil(m.sqrt(n))+1):
      for j in range(i, m.ceil(m.sqrt(n/(2*i)))+1):
          if n == i*j*(i+j):
             a = i
             b = j
             break
  return a, b  
print(decompose(9510432))
```

Comment: In your example, `b = 1256` is greater than `ceil(sqrt(n/(2*a))) = 891`. In other words, the upper bound on `b` is incorrect.

Comment: Nested loops don't make sense here as you can factor n completely with just one loop up to n\*\*0.5. After you factor it you can see if you can combine the factors to create the correct form, but note that it may be impossible to do so.

Answer (score 1):

You got your ranges wrong - you put `i` instead of `1`. Try this:

Replace:

```py
for j in range(i, m.ceil(m.sqrt(n/(2*i)))+1):
```

With:

```py
for j in range(1, m.ceil(m.sqrt(n/(2*i)))+1):
```